# What direction do I need to go in to complete this shopping cart assignment?

Tags: java

So I'm basically completely lost in regards to where I'm supposed to go with this assignment. This is what the assignment is asking me to do.

> "Part I:
>
> Design a class named Item that has information about items that are for sale in a store.  An Item has the following properties: Name, Vendor, Price, Weight, Taxable (a boolean field that indicates whether or not tax is charged on the item).
>
> Part II:
>
> Design a ShoppingCart class that contains items.  Several interesting methods are
>
> AddItem to insert an item to the cart.
>   CartTotal computes the total price of the cart.
>   CartTaxAmount receives the tax rate and computes the total tax to charge for the items currently in the cart.  Only Taxable items should be considered for this calculation.
>
> If it makes things easier, you can assume that the capacity of a ShoppingClass is fixed at 10 items.
>
> Keep in mind:
>
> Each class should have at least one constructor that receives arguments.
>   Make data members private and create accessor and mutator methods whenever necessary.
>
> Each class should have a toString method that you use to display the contents of the class.
>   Write a standalone function that allows a user to enter information for an Item and returns an Item to the calling function.
>   "

I'm just not wrapping my head around how to store a class item in an array of another class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Item {

//data members
private String Name;
private String Vendor;
private double Price;
private double Weight;
private boolean Taxable;

//constructor
Item(String conName, String conVendor, double conPrice, double conWeight, boolean Tax)
{
  Name = conName;
  Vendor = conVendor;
  Price = conPrice;
  Weight = conWeight;
  Taxable = Tax;
}

//Aceessor methods
public String getname(){
  return Name;
}

public String getvendor(){
  return Vendor;
}
public double getprice(){
  return Price;
}
public double getweight(){
  return Weight;
}
public boolean gettaxable(){
  return Taxable;
}

   public String toString()
  {
      String s = "Item Name is " + Name + " and the vendor is " + Vendor + ". The Price of the item is " + Price + " and the weight of the item is " + Weight + ". Item is taxable = " + Taxable + ".";
      return s; 
   }

   }


public class ShoppingCart {

   private Item[] itemsToBuy;
   private double taxRate;
   private int numItems;

   ShoppingCart(int capacity, double taxamount) {
      itemsToBuy = new Item[capacity];
      taxRate = taxamount;
      numItems = 0;
   }

   //Accessor methods

   public double gettaxRate(){
      return taxRate;
   }

   public int getItemNum() {
      return numItems;
   }
   public Item getitemsToBuy(int i) {
      return itemsToBuy[i];
   }

   //Methods

   public void AddItem() {



}
```

Comment: This looks like the kind of question you should ask your professor or TA.

Comment: I might suggest something like making AddItem take an item and then setting an element in the itemsToBuy array. You will probably want to also check if the cart is at capacity and not add an item if it is

Comment: Unfortunately throughout this entire semester she hasn't been able to answer a single question in a clear enough way for me to understand. The school isn't good enough where me complaining about it would get anything done. I've been self teaching myself all of this through google this entire way up. And I've been stuck on this assignment over the weekend trying to avoid coming here to ask how to get it done.

I don't want this done for me, I just want an explanation of the ideas that make a program like this work.

Comment: I think that's a complaint for every intro to programming course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your head up; you're on the right track. You can pass an item to the `AddItem` method and then insert it in your `itemsToBy` array. You just have to check to make sure there's room in the cart.

Try this:

```
public void AddItem(Item item) {
    if(numItems < itemsToBuy.length){
        itemsToBuy[numItems] = item; //insert item in the array
        numItems++; //increment the number of items
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your cart is full.");
    }
}
```

Why don't you try to implement a `removeLastItem()` method that removes the newest item from the cart. This should help you practice.

I recommend you watch the *Java for Complete Beginners* videos at [CaveofProgramming.com](https://caveofprogramming.com/categories/java-video/index.html). They were very helpful when I first started learning Java.

Comment: I am definitely, definitely going to do that extra removeLastItem part, just to reinforce this more.

Basically what I was having so much trouble understanding was the concept of how you create an array of items inside of a shopping cart that you then add an item created in the main method etc etc.

But when you showed me that segment of code, I still didn't fully get it. But then I just slowly piece by piece broke apart what you wrote trying to understand it. And I literally just broke through that mental barrier I was having. I was able to add a banana to a shopping cart :D.

Comment: I'm definitely going to keep working at this. For the most part, in a removeLastItem method, I get the premise. If I have a shopping cart of capacity 10, and I added 10 bananas, then I would go to the 10th element and remove that 10th banana. But what I'm not fully grasping is, what do I do to remove that banana? 

How does removing data from an array work?

Comment: You can remove an item from an array by setting its index equal to `null`; you just have to make sure you update your `numItems` afterward. Don't forget to address special cases (e.g. what if the cart is already empty?).

Comment: I did it! Just submitted it to my professor. Thank you guys so much. My professor is good, but i feel like most programming professors have a hard time putting things into laymans terms for the newbies . You guys did a great job in this for me.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot give you a ready made answer since this is obviously a homework assignment that *you* are supposed to do. But here are a few pointers that will help you understand the problem more:

**Item**

You need to create a public class called Item. That would look similar to what you already have, except a few changes that you could make:

1. Make the class public (public class Item)
2. You don't need a big constructor like this. Since you have the mutator methods, you can keep you constructor default like the following:

   ```
   public class Item {
       public Item() {
           // default constructor
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Change your getters/setters to use the getXyz and setXyz forms for each private member xyz. Notice the uppercase X, followed by lowercase yz.
4. You don't need to print a statement in your toString() method; it will become long and will fill up your console with unnecessary text. Instead make it simple and concise. Also, make a practice of using StringBuilder to build a string instead of using string concatenation. While string concatenation is not necessarily bad, StringBuilder keeps it less controversial :)

   ```
   public String toString() {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.append(getClass().getName()).append("\n")
         .append("\t name: ").append(getName()).append("\n")
         .append("\t vendor: ").append(getVendor()).append("\n");
       // do the same for all fields         

   return sb.toString();


   }
   ```

**ShoppingCart**

You will need a public class called ShoppingCart that would contain a List of Item objects; something like the following:

```
<pre>
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ShoppingCart {
    private final List<Item> items; // items can be of any size
    private double taxRate;

    public ShoppingCart() {
        this.items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    }

    // getter for items List
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }

    // instead of a setter, we have an 'adder' which
    // adds one element. you can call this method
    // to add items one at a time to the items List
    public void addItem(Item item) {
        this.items.add(item);
    }

    // or you can use a varargs adder, using which
    // you have the convenience of adding more than
    // one item at a time
    public void addItem(Item... items) {
        if(items != null && items.length > 0) {
           for(Item item : items) {
               this.items.add(item);
           }
        }
    }

    // getter for taxRate
    public double getTaxRate() {
        return this.taxRate;
    }

    // setter for taxRate
    public void setTaxRate(double taxRate) {
        this.taxRate = taxRate < 0 ? 0 : taxRate;
    }

    // item count is calculated; it's not a field getter
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.items.size();
    }

    // calculates total price without taxes
    public double calculateCartPriceTotalNoTax() {
        double total = 0.0;
        for(Item item : this.items) {
           total += item.getPrice();
        }

        return total;
    }

    // calculates total price with taxes
    public double calculateCartPriceTotal() {
        double totalNoTax = calculateCartPriceTotalNoTax();
        double total = totalNoTax * getTaxRate() / 100;

        return total;
    }

    // calculates total price with taxes (different way of doing it)
    public double calculateCartPriceTotal2() {
        double total = 0.0;
        double taxRate = getTaxRate();
        for(Item item : this.items) {
           total += (item.getPrice() * getTaxRate() / 100);
        }

        return total;
    }

    // toString method for the ShoppingCart.
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(getClass().getName()).append("\n")
          .append("\t items:             ").append(getItems()).append("\n")
          .append("\t taxRate:           ").append(getTaxRate()).append("\n")
          .append("\t totalPriceNoTax:   ").append(calculateCartPriceTotalNoTax()).append("\n")
          .append("\t totalPriceWithTax: ").append(calculateCartPriceTotal()).append("\n");

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
</pre>
```

**Note:**

May be you should start using Eclipse (or IntelliJ Idea, if you like). It will make writing Java code much easier, and will help you avoid many errors.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. Granted a lot of the syntax you use is way ahead of where I am so far, I'm going to spend some time trying to figure out some of the new things I'm seeing here to see if I can't get ahead of my class. And of course, I respect that you want to help and still allow me to figure the work out on my own ^^, there's now way I could learn otherwise.

Eclipse / IntelliJ Idea are other languages or basically other ways to write the code similar to jgrasp? And once again thank you so much, Both you and the comment above helped A LOTTTT on this one.

Comment: More than just showing me something, you helped me get a better grasp on the ideas behind it which really really means more to me than copy pasteing an answer for me.